# How would I modify this sendmail.php code so it sends in the right format

Tags: php, email, html-email, sendmail

I have a working sendmail.php file but when the user submits the form from the webpage it sends it to the site owner on one single line. Also, the headers are not appearing correctly.

I would like to just make it a very simple format.

When the message is received in a mail client like outlook it would show the Name of the person that is sending the email ($userName) and then on the second line the subject ( $userSubject ) and on the third line, it shows some of the message body.

Once the user clicks into the email it would show the the $message in paragraph form  (not all one line)
The seperated by a space and show the name, then next lin the phone# and next line the email of the sender.

Example of how the body would look:

---

Message: this is the body of the email. and it might be one line or multiple line depending on how the user wrote the email in the form.

For example lets say it was two lines and they submitted it like this.

Name: John Doe

Phone: 555-555-5555

Email: youremail@email.com

---

Here is the sendmail.php code I have that needs to be corrected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "Testing Website" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "captainObvious@helphelp.com" );

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$userName = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['username'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$senderPhone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['phone'] ) : "";
$userSubject = isset( $_POST['subject'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\s\S\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['subject'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $userName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $userSubject && $message) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "$userName" . $userSubject . "";
  $msgBody = 
  "" . $message .  
  " Name:". $userName .  
  " Email: ". $senderEmail . 
  " Phone: ". $senderPhone . "";
  $success = mail( $recipient, $headers, $msgBody );

  //Set Location After Successsfull Submission
  header('Location: contact.html?message=Successful');
}

else{
    //Set Location After Unsuccesssfull Submission
    header('Location: contact.html?message=Failed');    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain text, paragraphs are separated by two newlines. So you should replace single newlines with two newlines in the message.

Then you also need to put newlines between all the formatted lines that you're putting at the end of the message body.

```
  $message = str_replace("\n", "\n\n", $message);
  $msgBody = $message .  "\n\n" .
  " Name:". $userName .  "\n" .
  " Email: ". $senderEmail .  "\n" .
  " Phone: ". $senderPhone . "";
```

Comment: @bamar Appreciate the help. I added the lines and it works fine unless the user sends two paragraphs. If they do the recipient receives it with the message body as one line with the message and the second paragraph the name $userName is still on that line. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure why. There's nothing in your code that will remove the paragraph breaks.

Comment: You're not sending the email as HTML, so it should be sent verbatim, and the line breaks in `$_POST['message']` should be retained.

Comment: The `preg_replace()` call removes things like `From:` but doesn't remove the rest of the line after it.

Comment: I've updated the answer -- I added code to double the newlines in the message body, and add a paragraph break before the formatted lines at the end.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Once I put the new updated code in and I send two paragraphs I am getting double space now between the first and second paragraphs. Everything else looks good though. I just need to figure out how to make that basically be one space down rather than two now.

Comment: I changed the \n\n to \n\r in the ("\n", "\n\n", $message); line and it appears to have worked. Awesome stuff. One last question. How do I format the email client to show the sender on the first line, subject on 2nd line and the body of the message on the 3rd line in something like outlook? Currently it is black on the first line, name and subject on the 2nd line and the body on the 3rd. So I guess my issue is getting the name from the 2nd line to the first line.